# Proving that if $\;5\mid(a+11)\;$ and $\;5\mid(16-b),\;$ then $\;5\mid(a+b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Can you please help me a bit with this question?

> How do we show that $\;$ *if* $\;\;5\mid(a+11)\;$ and $\;5\mid(16-b),\;\;$ *then* $\;5\mid(a+b)\;$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: $(a+11)-(16-b)=a+b+11-16=a+b-5$. So if $5|a+b-5$ then...

Comment: @coffeemath: You mean "so *since* $5\mid a+b-5$..." I think.

Comment: @CameronBuie No I was summarizing the "if" part of the heading of the question as (implying) "if $5|a+b-5$". In other words getting to $5|a+b-5$ in one step, then expecting the OP to go one more step to get $5|a+b$ (which i didn't state).

Answer (score 3):

In general, for integers $a, b, n,$

$$n\mid a \;\;\text{and} \;\; n\mid b \quad \implies \quad n\mid (x - y)\tag{1}$$

So, if $5|(a+11)$ and $5|(16-b)$, then $5\mid [(a + 11)-(16-b)]\tag{by $(1)$}$
$$\iff 5\mid ((a + b) - 5) $$ $$\iff 5\mid (a + b),\;\; \text{ because}\;\; 5\mid -5\; $$ $$\therefore\quad 5\mid (a + b)\quad \checkmark$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $5 \mid (a+11)$, let $$(a+11) = 5m. \tag{1}$$

Again since $5 \mid (16-b)$, let $$(16-b) = 5n.\tag{2}$$

(1) - (2) gives you: $$(a+b-5) = 5(m-n) \quad \Rightarrow \quad (a+b) = 5(m+n+1).$$

Hence $5$ divides $(a+b)$ or $5 \mid(a+b)$.

Hope the answer is clear!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ \ \ 5\mid \color{#C00}{11\!+\!a},\color{#0A0}{b\!-\!16}\:\Rightarrow\: 5\mid 5\!+\!\color{#C00}{11\!+\!a}\!+\!\color{#0A0}{b\!-\!16} = a\!+\!b.\ $ Alternatively

$\rm\ mod\ 5\!:\, \ a\equiv -11,\ b\equiv 16\:\Rightarrow\: a\!+\!b \equiv -11\!+\!16\equiv 5\equiv 0$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$5\mid (a+11)\iff a=4\mod 5$$

$$5\mid(16-b)\iff b=1\pmod 5$$

so...

Comment: I think if the OP understood modular arithmetic, he would not be asking this question.

Comment: I think you're right, but anyway this may help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

$a|b$ can be written as $b \equiv 0 \pmod{a}$. So our two assumptions can be written as

$$
a+11 \equiv 0 \mod 5\\
16-b \equiv 0 \mod 5
$$
Subtracting the second equivalence from the first one, we have

$$
a+b-5 \equiv 0 \mod 5
$$
But of course, $5\equiv 0 \pmod5$, so we have
$$
a+b \equiv 0 \mod 5
$$
Therefore, $5|a+b$.